# Issue in creating and running a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have compiled a java project into a jar but I am having some issues when trying to run it

> java -jar XMltoCSV.jar
>   Error: Could not find or load main class XMLtoCSV.class

I have created a manifest file that contains:

> Main-Class: xmltocsv.XMLtoCSV

(there is a newline character in the manifest text file)

The XMLtoCSV.class does contain the main() method. I have been running this code to create the jar file:

> jar cvf XMLtoCSV.jar Manifest.txt xmltocsv/*.class

And I know its working because I get:

> jar cvfm XMLtoCSV.jar manifest.txt XMLtoCSV.class
>   added manifest
>   adding: XMLtoCSV.class(in = 4885) (out= 2492)(deflated 48%)

Why does it give me this error? Thanks in advance for the help

It seems I am also running into another error, what does it mean?:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: xmltocsv/XMLt
>   oCSV : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   Could not find the main class: xmltocsv.XMLtoCSV. Program will exit.

Comment: the package of the XMLtoCSV class is default? I.e. absent? What is the first line of the XMLtoCSV.java?

Comment: the first line is package xmltocsv;

Answer (score 4):

```
Main-Class: XMLtoCSV.class
```

it's not right.

You have to specify something like:

```
Main-Class: com.mydomain.XMLtoCSV
```

namely the fully qualified name of the class.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: could it also be Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass?

Comment: Yes, the fully qualified name consists of the package and the class name: package.className.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `.class` in your manifest.

**Update:**
What is the `package` of your main class? If your Java-File contains a statement such as

```
package com.google.common.base;
```

at the top. You need that package in your manifest. In your case that would be:

```
Main-Class: com.google.common.base.XMLtoCSV
```

If your class does **not** have such a package statemnent the error is something else.

*(Note that `com.google.common.base`is just an example of course.)*

Comment: it has the package xmltocsv, and changed it to Main-Class: xmltocsv.XMLtoCSV which will now run in the folder that I created but when I try and move it to another location (just the .jar) it give me the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For a jar be executable, you have to be concerned with two thing on the manifest file:

1- The 'Main-Class' entry must be pointing to the class that'll be launching the application, i.e. the class where you declared the main method to start your app.

2- After all entries on the manifest file, you have to leave three lines in blank (I never found a documentation explaining why that is required but always works for me).

The simplest MANIFEST file would look like the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.foo.FOO
```

Just remember to leave three lines in blank after the last entry.

Hope I have helped.